Why does Balarama drink wine?
In the grand festival of Vrishnis on the Raivataka mountain Balarama was drunk.

And there was the lord Haladhara (Valarama), roving at will, hilarious with drink, accompanied by (his wife) Revati, and followed by many musicians and vocalists. (Mahabharata , Adi Parva, chapter 221)

Also, in the Mausala Parva, we can see that

They prepared diverse kinds of viands and edibles and diverse kinds of wines and meat.


In the very sight of Krishna, Rama began to drink, with Kritavarma, Yuyudhana and Gada; and Vabhru also did the same. Then Yuyudhana, inebriated with wine, derisively laughing at and insulting Kritavarma in the midst of that assembly - Mahabharata 16.3 (Maushala Parva, Chapter 3)

Balarama is an avatar of Vishnu. Also, Vaishnavas worship him as one of the trio of Jagannatha, Balarama and Suvadra. Vaishnavas do not drink. But the very God they worship do drink. Isn't it strange? Why does Balarama drink? I can understand that other Vrishni heroes were drinking because they are human and ignorant. But why did Balarama drink wine?

wine is not prohibited for a kshatriya or vaishya :

manu smriti 11.94 :
gauḍī paiṣṭī ca mādhvī ca vijñeyā trividhā surā | yathaivaikā tathā sarvā na pātavyā dvijottamaiḥ || 94 ||
Wine should be understood to be of three kinds: (a) distilled from
molasses (Gauḍī), (b) distilled from grains (Paiṣṭī), and (c)
‘distilled from grapes’ (Mādhvī); as the one so all the rest should
never be drunk by the chief of the twice-born.—(94)
viṣṇu smriti 22.82 :
‘Distilled from sugar, or from the blossoms of Madhūka, or from flour; these three kinds of wine have to be discerned; as the one so
all; none of them should be tasted by the twice-born. Further, that
distilled from the blossoms of the Madhūka, from molasses, from the
Ṭaṅka fruit, from the Jujube fruit, from dates, from the bread-fruit,
from honey, Maireya wine, and wine made of the sap of the cocoanut
(coconut?) tree; these ten intoxicating drinks are unclean for the
Brāhmaṇa; but the Kṣatriya and the Vaiśya commit no wrong in
touching or drinking them.’

As balarAma was not a brahmana, above restriction doesnt apply for him
